# how to create a tree data structure by user defined tree level and child in python?

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, tree

I want to make tree data structure where user should define the level of tree and the child of the tree.
so if my input is 2 and child input is 2 then output should be

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \  / \
D   E F  G
```

data might be any thing..

Comment: *"data might be anyting"*: but if the user only provides *height* and *number of children*, then where does the data come from?

Comment: data come from user input . if the number of children is 3 so the user can input 3 time like  [A,B,C]..and the children data should be A B C

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a *full* tree: the leaves of such a tree are all at the same level.

You could do this with a BFS or DFS algorithm. As I don't know where you will get the data from, I just use random numbers here for the node values. This code uses a recursive DFS algorithm:

```
from random import randrange

class Node:
    def __init__(self, value, children=None):
        self.value = value
        self.children = children or []

    # helper function to allow a quick view on the tree structure
    def tolist(self):
        if self.children:
            return [self.value, [child.tolist() for child in self.children]]
        return self.value

def fulltree(height, childcount):
    if height == 0:
        return None
    if height == 1:  # Leaf node
        return Node(randrange(1000))
    # Recursion:
    return Node(randrange(1000), [fulltree(height-1, childcount) 
            for _ in range(childcount)])
```

You can run it as follows:

```
tree = fulltree(3, 2)  # A tree with height 3 and 2 children per internal node
print(tree.tolist())
```

This outputs something like:

```
[789, [[200, [196, 455]], [616, [32, 951]]]]
```

Note that *height* here means the *number* of levels in the tree, which in this case is 3 (not 2 as in your question).

Comment: Could you give some feed-back to this answer?

Comment: thank you very much...how can i insert data in the tree as user input like if the childcount  is 2 so user can input 2 data like [head, tail] and user can input the probability of the data like probability tree..